# Error handling and redirecting to Login page after JWT Refresh token is expired

Tags: redirect, next.js, error-handling, jwt, refresh-token

I'm using NextJS and we have JWT authentication implemented. However I have to do the following:
When the refresh token is expired, I have to redirect to login page. This is my code:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-return */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment */
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-member-access */
import axios from "axios";
import { BASE_URL, ResourcesEnums } from "../constants/url-resources";
import { deleteCookie, getCookie, setCookie } from "cookies-next";
import { COOKIE_KEY } from "../constants/keys";

const axiosInstance = axios.create({
  baseURL: BASE_URL,
});

class APIClient<T> {
  endpoint: string;

  constructor(endpoint: string) {
    this.endpoint = endpoint;
    axiosInstance.interceptors.request.use((config) => {
      const token = getCookie(COOKIE_KEY);
      config.headers.Authorization = token ? `Bearer ${token}` : null;
      config.withCredentials = true;
      return config;
    });

    // Add a response interceptor
    axiosInstance.interceptors.response.use(
      (response) => response,
      async (error) => {
        const originalRequest = error.config;

        // If the error status is 401 and there is no originalRequest._retry flag,
        // it means the token has expired and we need to refresh it
        if (error.response.status === 401 && !originalRequest._retry) {
          originalRequest._retry = true;

          try {
            const response = await axios.post(`${BASE_URL}${ResourcesEnums.REFRESH}`);

            const { newAccessToken } = response.data;
              originalRequest.headers.Authorization = `Bearer ${newAccessToken}`;
              setCookie(COOKIE_KEY, newAccessToken);
              originalRequest._retry = false;
              // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-argument
              return axiosInstance(originalRequest);

          } catch (error) {
            // Handle refresh token error or redirect to login
            deleteCookie(COOKIE_KEY);

          }
        }

        return Promise.reject(error);
      },
    );
  }

  get = async (id: number) => {
    return await axiosInstance
      .get<T>(`${this.endpoint}/${id}`)
      .then(
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
        // @ts-ignore
        (res) => res.data.data,
      )
      .catch((err) => {
        return err;
      });
  };

  getAll = async () => {
    return await axiosInstance
      .get<T[]>(this.endpoint)
      .then(
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
        // @ts-ignore
        (res) => res.data.data,
      )
      .catch((err) => {
        return err;
      });
  };

  put = async <U>(id: number, data: U) => {
    return await axiosInstance
      .put<T>(`${this.endpoint}/${id}`, data)
      .then(
        // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/ban-ts-comment
        // @ts-ignore
        (res) => res.data.data,
      )
      .catch((err) => {
        return err;
      });
  };

  post = async <U>(data: U) => {
    return await axiosInstance
      .post<T>(this.endpoint, data)
      .then((res) => {
        return { data: res.data, status: res.status };
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        return err;
      });
  };

  delete = async (id: number) => {
    return await axiosInstance
      .delete(`${this.endpoint}/${id}`)
      .then((res) => res.data)
      .catch((err) => {
        return err;
      });
  };
}

export default APIClient;
```

What should I change so that I can fulfil the condition about redirecting to login page?

1. I tried using router (next/navigation), but it is not allowed.
2. I tried with router (next/navigation) in the React component and it works, but to work everywhere, I should implemented it in every component, which is not a good idea.